# Intersecting a data frame based on the multiple columns

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames

```
> head(df1)
   Chromosome Start_Position End_Position       Gene
1:      chr12       46254706     46254706       ARID2
2:      chr17        7579849      7579849        TP53
3:       chr9       21974777     21974780      CDKN2A
4:       chr1       27105930     27105930      ARID1A
5:       chr1      201982973    201982973        ELF3
6:       chr3       89480459     89480459       EPHA3
> head(df2)
  Chromosome Start_Position End_Position
1          1          10583       863511
2          1       12841835     12854479
3          1       17231299     17232877
4          1      120380739    142540462
5          1      142540484    142684781
6          1      142685823    143462598
>
```

How I can intersect genes from df1 which are in the range of df2? Because both data frames have chromosome number, start and end but I don't know how to identify genes from df1 based on df2

I have tried

```
df1[df1$Start_Position%in%df2$Start_Position,]
```

But I obtain one gene

I also tried

```
> new_dataset <- df1 %>% right_join(df2, by=c("Chromosome","Start_Position"))
Error: Can't join on 'Start_Position' x 'Start_Position' because of incompatible types (character / integer)
>
```

Answer (score 1):

reformat df2 so that you have `chr1` is instead of `1`, then you basically have two bed files.  Then use `bedtools intersect`.  https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html

Answer (score 0):

In R:

```
> write.table(df1, 'df1.txt', quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=F, col.names=F)
> write.table(df2, 'df2.txt', quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

Convert both files to sorted BED:

```
$ sort-bed df1.txt > df1.bed
$ awk -v FS="\t" -v OFS="\t" '{ print "chr"$1 }' df2.txt | sort-bed - > df2.bed
```

Then map `df1` gene names to `df2` coordinates:

```
$ bedmap --echo --echo-map-id-uniq --delim '\t' df2.bed df1.bed > answer.bed
```

To bring back into R, e.g.:

```
> dfMap <- read.table('answer.bed', sep='\t', col.names=c('Chromosome', 'Start_Position', 'End_Position', 'Genes'), colClasses=c("factor", "numeric", "numeric", "character"))
```